# Serialize/ Deserialize C++ classes

Tags: c++, json, serialization, boost, thrift

I'm looking for a way to send C++ class between 2 clients aptication.
I was looking for a way doing so and all i can find is that I need to create for each Class Serialize/ Deserialize (to JSON for example) functions and send it over TCP/IP.
The main problem I'm faceing is that I have ~600 classes (some are classes including instances of others) that I need to pass which mean I need to spent the next writing Serialize/ Deserialize functions.

Is there any generic way writing Serialize/Deserialize functions ?
Is there any other way sending C++ classes ?

Thanks,
Guy Ergas.

Comment: boost serialize comes to mind, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Thrift is not such a bad choice. It will take the burden to generate the de/serialization code for you, based on a simple, easy to learn IDL syntax. One caveat might be that you can't have forward or circular references between types in Thrift. If that doesn't apply to you, Thrift could be your tool of choice.

Answer (score 2):

**Boost Serialization**
Although I haven't used it my self, it is very popular around my peers at work.
More info about it can be found in ["Boost (1.54.00) Serialization"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

**Thrift**
Thrift have a very limited serialize functionality which I don't think fits your requirements. But it can help you "move" the data from one client to anther even if they are using different languages.
More info about it can be found in ["Thrift: The Missing Guide"](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/)

Comment: **Thrift has serializing functionality** indeed (that's why it is positioned as an RPC and serialization framework). Technically the serialization is more or less a bonus effect, 'cause it's needed  anyway for RPC.

Comment: @JensG : Thrift serialization is only for some basic types and common data-struct (map, set and list) but it doesn't have out-of-the-box serialization for user custom class.

Comment: It depends what you are calling an user defined custom class. Thrift allows for structs that you define which are then translated into classes. It may not fit your needs, but it has serialization Support, contrary to what the answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Framework at all? Qt and MFC for example have built in Serialization that would make your task easier. Otherwise I would guess that you'd need to spend at least some effort on each of the 600 classes.

As recommended above Boost Serialization is probably a good way to go, you can send the serialized class over Tcp using Boost Asio too:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Alternatively, there is a C++ API for Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf):
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/

Answer (score 1):

try [s11n](http://s11n.net/) or [nosjob](http://fossil.wanderinghorse.net/repos/nosjob/index.cgi/index)

> s11n (an abbreviation for serialization) is an Open Source project
>   focused on the generic serialization of objects (i.e., object
>   persistence) in the C++ programming language.
>
> nosjob, a C++ library for generating and consuming JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in ASN.1. It's not necessarily the easiest to use and tools/libraries are a little hard to come by (Objective Systems at http://www.obj-sys.com/index.php is worth a look, though not free).

However the big advantage is that it is very heavily standardised (so no trouble with library version incompatibilities) and most languages are supported one way or another. Handy if you need support across multiple platforms. It also does binary encodings, so its way less bloaty than XML (which it also supports). I chose it for these reasons and didn't regret it.

Comment: From Wikipedia: [Abstract Syntax Notation One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn.1) (ASN.1) is a standard and notation that describes rules and structures for representing, encoding, transmitting, and decoding data in telecommunications and computer networking. The formal rules enable representation of objects that are independent of machine-specific encoding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at linux platform , You can directly use `json.h` library for serialization.
Here is sample code i have come across :)

> [Json Serializer](http://newbcoding.blogspot.in/2014/10/serializing-json-object-c.html)